# Populate dropdown list from database using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to populate the dropdown list from database using jQuery. But when i tried, i am getting empty response. see below code I didn't see any error.

PHP code to get data:

```
if ($dat=="driver") {
    $q = "select * from drivers";
    $sql = mysql_query($q);
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, true)){
        $data[] = $row; 
    };
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$.getJSON("get-data.php?dat=driver",function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,val) {
        $("#night_Shift_text").append(
            $("<option></option>").val(value.id).html(value.id)
        );     
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id='night_Shift_text'><option></option></select>
```

Debug console:

[image]

Comment: what `data` contains ? have you debug it ?

Comment: Are you sure `$dat` has the value you expect and the `if` condition is hitting? Have you made any attempt to debug this at all?

Comment: how to debug it

Comment: Print your data variable in console and use accordingly. The problem is surely in parsing object

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem. But change it to `if($dat === "driver"){ ... }`. And remove the semi-colon after your `while` loop

Comment: @NoGodButAllah. Please change your display name as people will comment different words and this will is not right please i hope you understand.

Comment: Also, pass `value` as a parameter in your **jQuery**

Comment: did u see attached picture it show the error

Comment: @Mairaj if you do not like the name of a user, you can flag the post and choose in need of moderator intervention and say you find the name offensive

Comment: @Pete i didn't know that thanks for info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string to store your option, and then append it to the select tag. Then, please check that data is there in the val.

```
$.getJSON("get-data.php?dat=driver",function(data){
    var stringToAppend = "";
    $.each(data,function(key,val) {

       stringToAppend += "<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.id + "</option>";

    });

    $("#night_Shift_text").html(stringToAppend);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong variable `value`. You need to use `val`

```
        $("<option></option>").val(val.id).html(val.id);
```